# Adding a value to a 'datetime2' column caused an overflow

Tags: sql, sql-server, dateadd

I know why I'm seeing this error, it's because some of my `locationDeletionDate` is '9999-12-31 00:00:00.0000000', and adding 90 days to the `locationDeletionDate` (as I do in my query) causes the error in the title:

```
...WHERE                
(bpj.JobStatus = 'Live') 
AND (l.locationEffectiveDate <= SYSDATETIME()) 
AND (dateadd(d,90,l.locationDeletionDate) >= SYSDATETIME())...
```

I guess what I need is a conditional `CASE` in my `WHERE`-clause to ensure the date will not error if 90 days are added? Or is there a more elegant way?

Comment: Why not just add one more predicate to your where clause? AND l.locationDeletionDate < '9999-01-01' or something along those lines. Why are you using such a ridiculously large value anyway? I would think that NULL would be more appropriate.

Comment: I wiould agree with @sean why store 9999 dates anyways?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use this approach to solve you issue

```
...WHERE                
(bpj.JobStatus = 'Live') 
AND (l.locationEffectiveDate <= SYSDATETIME()) 
AND (l.locationDeletionDate >= dateadd(d, -90, SYSDATETIME())...
```

In this case you also solve a performance issue. Your predicate becomes SARGable.